# SpriteRenderer перекрывает Canvas

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Спрайт противника перекрывает UI интерфейс. Sorting layer не помогает, как и перемещение по оси Z, перемещение объекта противника вверх и вниз по иерархии.

[image: Наложение]

[image: Второй пример]

[image: Sprite renderer]

[image: Объект, на который накладывается SpriteRenderer]

[image: Canvas]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос скрины обсуждаемых компонентов и будем думать

Comment: `SpriteRenderer` окей, а вместо `Image` надо увидеть сам `Canvas` компонент, он висит на одноименном объекте по умолчанию. И почему оригинальные скрины из Editor View, а не Game View, там ситуация такая же?

Comment: В Game View такая же история, объект противника всё равно накладывается. Добавил Canvas компонент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве `Render Mode` у вас выбран `Screen Space - Camera`, это значит, что весь канвас будет рисовать так, будто он находится на плоскости, на заданном удалении от камеры. Можно подобрать подходящий `Plane Distance` который вас устроит, сейчас он довольно большой и очевидно находится дальше от камеры, чем спрайт персонажа.
Могу посоветовать попробовать `Screen Space - Overlay` как `Render Mode`, он работает более очевидно - просто рисует интерфейс, без привязки камеры(даже если камеры нет, или выключена).